# Variable not declared before it is used with DAO

Tags: vb.net, dao

I'm using DAO (been asked not to use ADO.NET) to update an Access database. I'm currently thus far, however, VB2008 is telling me that the variable "daoengine" is not declared before it is used. What am I doing wrong in the following code?

```
Function update_db()
    Dim daoengine As DAO.DBEngine
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    dbs = daoengine.OpenDatabase("Project.mdb")
    rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Log", dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)

End Function
```

Comment: Are you using DAO from within VB.NET or MS-Access?

Comment: I'm using it in VB.NET to access an Ms-Access database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say

```
Dim daoengine As DAO.DBEngine
```

you're just creating a variable, `daoengine`, but it doesn't actually point to anything.  You need to do this afterwards:

```
Set daoengine = New DAO.DBEngine
```

You can also type `Dim daoengine As New DAO.DBEngine`, but it's better to do it in the two lines above.  If you put the `New` in the `Dim` line, you create what's called an "auto-instancing" variable which can magically come to life again after you thought you'd disposed of it.

For more details see the **Don't Use Auto-Instancing Object Variables** here:  [Declaring Variables (in VBA)](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should have

```
Dim daoengine As New DAO.DBEngine
```

instead of

```
Dim daoengine As DAO.DBEngine
```

Comment: How would I then go about updating the recordset using data from Field.Text ?